# Trouble getting the Chrome browser on a Mac to connect securely over SSL/TLS to Apache 2.4 on Centos

Tags: google-chrome, security, apache-http-server, ssl, certificate

We operate multiple sites that run the Leaf webapp. Our configuration runs on Centos 7.9, with a .NET Web API and Apache 2.4.

The system is used only by staff who access our Intranet. It uses a self-signed institutional root certificate, an intermediate certificate, and a server certificate signed (issued) by the intermediate certificate. `openssl` shows the chain:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect leaf.ourdomain:443 -showcerts -CAfile path_to_root_cert/RootCert.cer 2> /dev/null | egrep "Certificate chain| s:| i:"
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=leaf.ourdomain
   i:/DC=org/DC=our_dc/CN=Our system CA
 1 s:/DC=org/DC=our_dc/CN=Our system CA
   i:/CN=Our System
```

I have obfuscated the name of our institution, but left everything else the same.

Chrome is running on a Mac and configured to use the root certificate in the Mac's Keychain Access app. This obtains secure, private connections for a production deployment of Leaf.

I'm configuring a VM clone of the production system. We've created a new private key and a server certificate signed by the intermediate certificate. `httpd.conf` has been modified for the new domain name. The server certificate, private key, and intermediate certificate have been stored on the server and these httpd attributes now point to them:

```
  SSLCertificateFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/omop-leaf-temp_hpc_our_domain_ssl.cer"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/private/omop-leaf-temp_hpc_our_domain_ssl.key"
  SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/Intermediate.cer"
```

The server's domain name appears to check out. Obfuscated, it is `omop-leaf-temp.hpc.our_domain`. This name is used for 1) the URL of the https request, 2) the error message reported by Chrome, and 3) the `CN` in the `SSLCertificateFile`. This is confirmed by

```
$ openssl x509 -text -in ./omop-leaf-temp_xxxx.cer| grep CN= | grep omop
        Subject: C=US, ST=xxx, L=xxx, O=Our System, OU=xxx, CN=-hpc.our_domain/emailAddress=leaf-support@xxx
```

But the Chrome instance that obtains secure connections to the production system fails to do so in the VM clone:
[image: Chrome fails to establish a secure connection to the server in the VM clone]

The "PEM encoded chain" identifies 3 certs. In order, they are `SSLCertificateFile`, `SSLCertificateChainFile`, and our self-signed root certificate that Chrome obtains through Keychain Access (I presume). This seems fine to me.

`httpd` does not report errors in the logs (including `error_log`, `leaf_access_log`, and `leaf_ssl_error_log`) when Chrome attempts a connection. `LogLevel` is `warn`.

I am perplexed. Why does Chrome report `Your connection is not private` and `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` when the CN is right and the certificate chain is good? What can I do to further investigate and fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: **Does your server (leaf) cert have SAN** (SubjectAlternativeName) extension and does it contain the server's name(s)? For several years now Chrome _requires_ SAN, and if that is missing it gives the (misleading) error you show. Other browsers _prefer_ SAN if present -- which it is in all certs from _public_ CAs since about 2010 -- but accept CN if SAN is absent. PS: CentOS 3.9 ???!!!

Comment: Good observation Ram. I assumed that since `openssl req` appends the email to the CN that SSL/TLS code used by Chrome would know to strip it off.
To test that I've created a cert without an email address.
`openssl req -text -in omop-leaf-temp_hpc_mssm_edu_ssl.csr | grep Subject:
        Subject: C=US, ST=New York, L=City, O=Our organization, OU=Our unit, CN=omop-leaf-temp.hpc.mssm.edu`
But, Chrome still reports `Your connection is not private` and `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`. How can I get Chrome to give a more complete error, or simulate Chrome at the CLI?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: RE CentOS version, my typo. It is 7.9.

Comment: Whew! 7.9 is much saner. Now, what about SAN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server's cert needs to have a SubjectAlternativeName (SAN) extension that contains the server's name, as pointed out by @dave_thompson_085.

This enables both Chrome (Version 102.0.5005.115) and Safari (Version 15.0) to establish secure connections with the server.

The cert was created using

```
openssl req \
-newkey rsa:4096 \
-nodes \
-keyout omop-leaf-temp_redacted.key \
-out omop-leaf-temp_redacted.csr \
-config csr_with_san.conf \
-days 730 \
-batch \
-verbose
```

with this config file

```
[ req ]
default_bits              = 2048
default_md              = sha256
distinguished_name    = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions     = req_ext
prompt = no

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName                 = US
stateOrProvinceName       = New York
localityName                  = New York City
organizationName          = redacted
organizationalUnitName  = redacted
commonName                  = omop-leaf-temp.redacted
emailAddress                  = redacted

[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName          = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1                   = omop-leaf-temp.redacted
```

I urge the developers of the code that evaluates whether a client has established a secure connection to provide a clear error indicating that the cert needs to have a SAN rather than the incorrect error `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`.

Answer (score 0):

The Common Name looks wrong:

> ./omop-leaf-temp_xxxx.cer| grep CN= | grep omop
> Subject: C=US, ST=xxx, L=xxx, O=Our System, OU=xxx, CN= "

but "-hpc.our_domain/emailAddress=leaf-support@x"
is rather different than "omop-leaf-temp.hpc.our_domain"

Comment: Good observation Ram. I wondered about that too, but assumed that since `openssl req` appends the email to the CN that SSL/TLS code used by Chrome would know to strip it off.
To test that I've created a cert that doesn't have an email address.

Comment: So you tested it and? It's been over 20 years since putting the email address in a 'structured' CN was done... and never for SSL/TLS certificates, only for S/MIME (email mostly). The CN is irrelevant if you are using the SAN extension to hold the host name. Best practice is to put primary in CN and then a list of DNS names your server might respond from in the SAN.

Comment: @ArthurG no, email is not 'appended' to CN, it is a separate attribute in the _DN_ (Distinguished Name). The default _display format_ is inconsistent and uses comma for some attributes but slash for email; do `openssl x509 -subject -nameopt multiline -in $file` to see. SAN is not only better as Ram says but _required_ for Chrome as I said; did you check or set it?